# python grouping and further grouping

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have tried different ways to group data in two different columns and bright weightage factor. Sadly I am very new to python. I have gonde through few questions and tried to come up with half the solution. Could you please help me with the remaining or atleast provide an idea?
below is the mock code:

```
    data = pd.DataFrame({'sku_id' : ['s1', 's1', 's1', 's2','s2','s2','s3','s3','s3'], 
             'product_id' : ['p1','p1','p2','p1','p1','p1','p2','p2','p3']})
count_series = data.groupby(['product_id','sku_id']).size()
print('-'*30)
print(count_series)
print('-'*30)
agg_count = count_series.to_frame(name = 'weight').reset_index()
print(agg_count)
print('-'*30)
```

The Output is as:

```
------------------------------
product_id  sku_id
p1          s1        2
            s2        3
p2          s1        1
            s3        2
p3          s3        1
dtype: int64
------------------------------
  product_id sku_id  weight
0         p1     s1       2
1         p1     s2       3
2         p2     s1       1
3         p2     s3       2
4         p3     s3       1
------------------------------
```

Can someone please help me to further group ***the SKU_ID column*** based on their combination and occurances. (it is something like a recommendation engine)

Desired Output:

```
-----------------------
    sku_id    weight
    s1 & s2     1
    s2 & s3     0
    s3 & s1     1
-----------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can try the below:

```
import itertools
#Replicating your steps:
m = data.groupby(['product_id','sku_id']).size().reset_index(name='weight')
#group on `product_id` and apply a `tuple on `sku_id` print to see results
n=m.groupby('product_id')['sku_id'].apply(tuple).reset_index()
#create combinations by list(itertools.combinations(m.sku_id.unique(),2))
#check if any combination matches tuple and apply astype(int) for int results
n['new']=n.sku_id.isin((itertools.combinations(m.sku_id.unique(),2))).astype(int)
print(n)

  product_id    sku_id  new
0         p1  (s1, s2)    1
1         p2  (s1, s3)    1
2         p3     (s3,)    0
```

Note that `s2` and `s3` are present in the `sku_id` column. So considering just that row will always give you a combination, so my output is a little different.

Comment: This works very good. Can you please help to explain what is used here.? namely tuple, and line no (4) please.

Comment: @Ashwin i have added the explaination as inline comments. :) Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you sir. :) thanks a lot. Will keep this post alive for any doubts or help

Comment: Hi Anky: I have a doubt.! The new column you had formed right? does it show us the recommendation ? (say like s1 & s2 combination appeared 3 times; s1 & s3 combination appeared 10 times) something like that?